# User input right to left, iOS App Development, SwiftUI, TextFields, Currency

Tags: ios, swiftui, user-input, textfield, xcode14

**Overall Context**
I begin with the below View, which gives me the result image of "Total 0.00" that follows.

**My problem:** When I enter in values, it either adds the numbers at the beginning or the end of the `"0.00"` placeholder String in `TextField`. I can highlight and overwrite the placeholder text of the `TextField` in the preview with keyboard input.

**My goal:** I want the input sequence to run as such:

1. User inputs the first digit of their purchase amount
2. This first digit replaces the `0` in the 2nd decimal place of the placeholder text in `TextField`.
3. As the user input the remaining digits of their purchaser price, the numbers move right to left.

**Example:** Let's say the user's purchase price was 29.50:

1. User inputs 2
2. The `TextField` changes from `0.00` to `0.02`
3. User inputs 9, the `TextField` then reads `0.29`

This continues until the user finishes inputing 29.50.

**TLDR** I want the input to run right to left, keeping the decimal in the appropriate place.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
  @State private var total: String = "0.00"

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Form {
        Section(header: Text("Detail")) {
          HStack {
            Text("Total")
            TextField("0.00", text: $total)
              .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
              .foregroundColor(.gray)
              .frame(width: 120)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[Result of the above ContentView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLpMz.png)

**Attempt to use `.onEditingChanged`**

I replaced the `TextField` with the below. Trying the below code returns the following error on line the line with `.onEditingChanged` "Value of type 'some View' has no member 'onEditingChanged'"

I learned `.onEditingChanged` is not a property of `TextField` so I needed to try another approach....

```
TextField("0.00", text: $total)
    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
    .frame(width: 120)
    .onEditingChanged { value in
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        if let result = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(value) ?? 0)) {
            self.total = result
        }
    }
```

**Attempt to use `.onCommit {}`**

I replaced the `.onEditingChanged { value in` from that attempt with `.onCommit {`. This resulted in the *same error message*. It read "Value of type 'some View' has no member 'onCommit'"

```
TextField("0.00", text: $total)
  .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
  .foregroundColor(.gray)
  .frame(width: 120)
  .onCommit {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    if let result = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(self.total) ?? 0)) {
      self.total = result
    }
  }
```

I am at a loss as how to achieve my goal. Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: try using `.onChange()`

Comment: Unfortunately in my experience, the only way to do this that's sustainable long-term is to wrap a `UITextField` in a `UIViewRepresentable`